# HTML-5 picture tag trying to understand the loading logic

Tags: html, image, media-queries, image-resizing

I am playing around with the HTML5 `<picture>` tag and I am trying to understand how it works.

**What I have got so far:**

I've created the little snippet below:

```html
<picture>
  <source srcset="https://placehold.co/360/webp 360w, https://placehold.co/768/webp 768w, https://placehold.co/1280/webp 1280w, https://placehold.co/2560/webp 2560w" type="image/webp" sizes="(max-width: 360px) 360px, (max-width: 768px) 768px, (max-width: 1280px) 1280px, (max-width: 2560px) 2560px">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/150/webp" alt="this is a fallback">
</picture>
```

As far as I've understood, it should load the best fitting (sources are more important than the image as it is the fallback) image-source from `placehold.co` for the given sizes.

**What does not work**

- The sources change with the viewport, but it does not behave as expected. The changes seem to be happening somewhat arbitrarily.
- For example, I'd imagined the picture-element to load up the image with a resolution of `360px` on a viewport width of `<360px`, but it loads the `768px` variant instead. When I make it bigger it will load the `2560px` straight without loading the smaller variant first and it will never go back to loading smaller image sizes when I resize the viewport. I've read [this mdn article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture?retiredLocale=en) here, but I did not get the desired result for my use-case.

**Questions:**

How does the loading logic work with the different viewports for the `<picture>` element?

- For now, I fail to understand the loading logic behind the different sizes.
- Can I enforce the sizes or at least gain more control? I mean for a screen of `360px` I might want to load a small image that fits `<360px` and not be forced to load `768px` or even a bigger image.

**I do understand, however, why it is beneficial to have source-sets as such and different image variants. That is not the question here.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested your code snippet in *Chrome Version 114.0.5735.106 (Official Build) (x86_64)* and *Firefox 113.0.2 (64-bit)*.

Seems to behave as expected - viewports up to 360px get the 360px image, viewports from 361px on get the 720px image, and so on. It's a little hard to see the resolution-label on the higher res images, as they go flying off the viewport.

---

### Ideas

Some things that may shed some light on the issues you're seeing:

- **Images not changing when making the viewport smaller**: Your browser might cache the 768px image. When you then make the viewport smaller, **it doesn't switch to the smaller one** because hey, it already got a larger one here. (Chris Coyer mentions this [here](https://css-tricks.com/a-guide-to-the-responsive-images-syntax-in-html/#aa-browsers-choice), Kevin Powell mentions caching in Chrome specifically [here](https://youtu.be/2QYpkrX2N48?t=1004))
- **Breakpoints behaving differently from the ones specified**: you might wanna **check the *DPR*** (device pixel ratio) of the screen your using. You can also set it in your dev tools. *DPR* is also a factor in what image the browser chooses to download, mentioned in the spec [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-picture-element):

> The picture element is a container which provides multiple sources to its contained img element to allow authors to declaratively control or give hints to the user agent about which image resource to use, based on the **screen pixel density**, viewport size, image format, and other factors.

(emphasis mine)

---

### Semi-relevant aside

BTW It seems that you can also cut out the whole `sizes` attribute in your specific case, because you're basically setting a size of `100vw` for each viewport. `100vw` is the default that the browser assumes, when there's no `sizes` attribute given. (Can't find it clearly stated in the specs, but here's [Kevin Powell talking about it in a video](https://youtu.be/2QYpkrX2N48?t=1269))

This is extra weird, because [MDN states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/srcset):

> Note: If the srcset attribute uses width descriptors, the sizes attribute must also be present, or the srcset itself will be ignored.

This doesn't seem to be the case on either of the browsers mentioned at the top, at least. From reading about this topic, I gather that the spec gives considerable freedom as to how user agents implement the decision of which image to actually fetch over the network.

Here's your code with no `sizes` attribute:
(I added `max-width: 100%; height: auto` so that the resolution label stays legible)

```html
<picture>
  <source srcset="https://placehold.co/360/webp 360w, https://placehold.co/768/webp 768w, https://placehold.co/1280/webp 1280w, https://placehold.co/2560/webp 2560w" type="image/webp">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/150/webp" alt="this is a fallback" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto">
</picture>
```

Comment: I had the same thoughts when I was writing this question and also a bit afterward when I did more analysis work. It is clear to me that it will try to use the cached variant and also the DP thing is only logical. However, you are right about the size attribute. I just used it to make sure I am hard-constraining it for the use case I've been after. I think I should just omit the attribute in this case, as you've stated. I'd still like to understand better why it did not work though. To me, it looks like it should just work in the same way. Thank you for the effort and detailed explanation.